# What is the correct pronunciation of "often"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, grammar, pronunciation

Should people pronounce **often** with the hard "t"? I pronounce it **offen**.

Which is correct?

Comment: I think dictionaries provide pronunciation guides.